# Exception: Address unavailable Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, urlfetch

I'm trying to get the value of class "rank_view" from a URL in parameter from Zacks.com website.
Here is the script I did:

```
function ZacksRank (url) {
    
  //url.toString().trim();
  // Get the content of that site as a string
  var d = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  
  // String to search (in your case following the class value)
  // Note that the string to be search contains 19 characters
  var search = 'class="rank_view">'; 
  
  // Get the index where the data we are interested is found in the string
  var index = d.search(search);
  
  // Get the character at that index (plus 19 is because search returns the
  // index of the first character of the search, in this case it would return
  // the index of c (of class) and therefore we must add to the index the length
  // of our string
  var value = d.charAt(index+search.length);
  
  return(value);
  
}
```

I call the function like that:

```
=zacksrank("http://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/abbv")
```

but I get the following error message:

```
Exception: Address unavailable: http://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/abbv
```

Anyone will be able to help please?
Big thanks :)
Gabriel

Comment: Hi, Did you finally find the root cause and a fix / workaround for this? Thank you.

Comment: Hi @FMFF, no unfortunately I didn't find the root cause for it :(

Comment: Make sure SSL is set up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This error means that the page you are trying to fetch is currently unavailable. There is nothing wrong with your script. The "zacks.com" website is not responding at all.

To prove it you can use a URL of a webpage that you know for sure it will work, for example "https://www.google.com".

Comment: Hi Alessandro, thanks for your quick response.
Indeed, I called the function with =zacksrank("http://www.google.com") & it returned me something (like no error).

But I don't understand why it doesn't work with the other url, because I can access the website https://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/abbv in my browser without any problem.

Do I have to adjust something in my script to make it work with "https://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/abbv" in parameter please?

Comment: I don't think so, it doesn't work in my browser. I am positive the the error is on the website side, not on the script.

Comment: I just tried with another URL & same problem: https://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/CSCO

I can access this URL https://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/CSCO in my browser without any error or warning & I call these URL in the following IMPORTXML formula & it works (but not all the time, thats why I try to do it through a script): 
=left(IMPORTXML("https://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/"&B13,"//p[@class='rank_view']"),13)
Thanks

Comment: I cannot visit this website from my browser. You should see if they are filtering the access somehow.

Comment: hmm that's very strange for the website from the browser. thanks for checking

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem is because the site or framework that it was made has a type of bot blocker that limits requests.

To solve this, try to include the agent inside your headers:

**Step 1**: Create a request from your browser and access the first request on your Network window:

[image]

**Step 2**: Locate user-agent and other key fields at:

Request Headers > User-Agent: (maybe it will be the last field)

**Step 3**: This is my request example:

```
  var options = {
    headers: {
      'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/254.354 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.0.0 Safari/254.254',
      'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9saf,image/,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.ds,application/signed-exchange;v=bas;q=0.7',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
      'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,pt-BR;q=0.8,pt;q=0.7',
      'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    },
  };


  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  return response.getContentText()
```

**Extra** : Google scripts allows you to use someting like a setTimeOut inside a loop:

Use this to prevent request limits:

```
function teste () {
    let content = await getContentGs(url);
    let siteIsRunning = false

    while (!siteIsRunning) {
      if (content != 'try again') {
        siteIsRunning = true
      } else {
        content = await getContentGs(url);
      }
    }
    return content
}


async function getContentGs(url) {

  var options = {YOUR OPTIONS HERE};

  try {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    return response.getContentText()

  } catch (error) {
    console.log('try again', error.message)
    Utilities.sleep(2 * 1000) // <-------------- USE THIS
    return 'try again'
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the above code several times and had no errors.
Nevertheless direct fetching [www.zacks.com](http://www.zacks.com) data seems to be inefficient in general.
My suggestion is using https://quote-feed.zacks.com/index.php?t=ABBV endpoint instead. Below is the code:

```
function ZacksRank(ticker) {
  const URL = 'https://quote-feed.zacks.com/index.php?t=' + ticker;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL);
  if (response.getResponseCode() != 200) return 'Unavailable';
  var j = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(j, null, 2));  // More info, if required
  return j[ticker].zacks_rank;  // Zacks rank value
}
```

In particular for the ABBV ticker it can be used in the following way:  `=ZacksRank("ABBV")`

You might wish to get more ticker info from the same endpoint if you look at the Logger output. The variable `j` already contains it.